# I keep getting subscript out of range don't know how to fix it

Tags: c++, arrays, file, random, input

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

const int MAX_NUMS = 200;   // Constant for the maximum number of words.
const int MAX_GUESSES = 8;
const string LETTERS = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

char   inputLetter();
int    findChar(char letter, string&word);
string getGuessedWord(string&secretWord, string&lettersGuessed);
string getLettersGuessed(char letter, string&lettersGuessed, int n);
void display(string&lettersGuessed, string&wordGuessed, int num, int pos);
bool isDone(string wordGuessed);

int main()
{
string oneWord;                 // holds one word from input file
string secretWord;              // holds secret word to be guessed
string words[MAX_NUMS];         // holds list of words from input file
int randomValue;                // holds index of secret word
int count = 0;                  // holds number of words in the file

// Declare an ifstream object named myFile and open an input file
ifstream myFile;
myFile.open("P4Words.txt");

// Exit program if cannot open file for input
if (!myFile)
{
    cout << "Error: Unable to open file for input" << endl;
    return 0;
}

// Input words from a file into words array
// Add your code here ...
myFile >> oneWord;
while (!myFile.eof())
{
    words[count] = oneWord;
    count++;
    myFile >> oneWord;
}
myFile.close();
cout << count << " words loaded." << endl;

srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(0)));

// Select a secret word
// Add your code here ...
secretWord = words[rand() % (count + 1) ];

// Possible useful variables the loop
string lettersGuessed = ""; // holds letters guessed so far
string wordGuessed;         // holds current word guessed like �_ pp_ e�
int incorrectGuesses = 0;   // holds number of incorrect guesses so far
char letter;                // holds a guessed letter
bool done = false;          // have not guessed the word yet
int num = 8; int pos;
cout << "Welcome to the game, Hangman V1 by Your Name!" << endl;
cout << "I am thinking of a word that is " << secretWord.length()
    << " letters long." << endl;

// Set up a loop to input guesses and process
// Add your code here ...
do
{
    letter = inputLetter();
    pos = findChar(letter, secretWord);
    wordGuessed = letter;
    lettersGuessed = getLettersGuessed(letter, lettersGuessed, 8 - num);
    wordGuessed = getGuessedWord(secretWord, lettersGuessed);
    display(lettersGuessed, wordGuessed, num, pos);
    done = isDone(wordGuessed);
    num--;

} while ((num > 1) && (done == false));


// Check for won or lost
// Add your code here ...
if (done == false)
{
    cout << "sorry you lose..." << endl;
}
if (done == true)
{
    cout << "congratulations! " << endl;
}

system("pause");    // stop program from closing, Windows OS only

return 0;
}

// Add function definitions here ...
char inputLetter()
{
int i;
char letter;

do
{
    cout << "please guess a letter: " << endl;
    cin >> letter;

    for (i = 0; i < 25; i++)
    {
        if (letter == LETTERS[i])
        {
            return letter;
        }
    }

    if (letter != LETTERS[i])
    {
        cout << "Oops! That is an invalid character." << endl;
    }
} while (letter != LETTERS[i]);

}

int findChar(char letter, string &word)
{
int i = 0;  int pos = 0; bool found = false;
do
{
    if (word[pos] == letter)
    {
        return pos;
        found = true;
    }
    pos++;

} while (pos<word.length() - 1);

if (found == false)
{
    return -1;
}


}
string getGuessedWord(string&secretWord, string&letterGuessed)
{
string temp;
temp = secretWord;

for (size_t k = 0; k <= temp.length() - 1; k++)
{
    temp[k] = '_';
}
for (size_t i = 0; i <= temp.length() - 1; i++)
{
    for (size_t j = 0; j <= temp.length() - 1; j++)
    {
        if (letterGuessed[i] == secretWord[j])
        {
            temp[j] = letterGuessed[i];
        }
    }

}



return temp;
}
string getLettersGuessed(char letter, string&lettersGuessed, int n)
{

string temp;
temp = letter;
lettersGuessed.insert(n, temp);
return lettersGuessed;

}

void display(string&lettersGuessed, string&wordGuessed, int num, int pos)
{
if (pos != -1)
{
    cout << "You have " << num << " guesses left." << endl;
    cout << "Letters guessed so far: " << lettersGuessed << endl;
    cout << "Good guess!: " << wordGuessed << endl;
    cout << "-----------------------------------------------------" << endl;
}
if (pos == -1)
{
    cout << "You have " << num << " guesses left." << endl;
    cout << "Letters guessed so far: " << lettersGuessed << endl;
    cout << "Oops! that letter is not my word: " << wordGuessed << endl;
    cout << "-----------------------------------------------------" << endl;
}

}

bool isDone(string wordGuessed)
{
bool done = false; int k = 0;
for (size_t i = 0; i <= wordGuessed.length() - 1; i++)
{
    if (wordGuessed[i] == '_')
    {
        k++;
    }
}

if (k == 0)
{
    done = true;

}
return done;
}
```

it says subscript is out of range I need help to fix it

let me know how to fix it please its a project that is due very soon 
that's all I got so far

Comment: Where does it error out ? Do you expect us to find this in the horrible formatting ? + http://sscce.org/

Comment: Step one would be producing a *minimal* example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i <= temp.length() - 1; i++)
```

to:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i <= letterGuessed.length() - 1; i++)
```